# Get path to Blender executable

Tags: python, path

How to get Blender executable's file path in a Python script?

`__file__` gives me my addon's path, but I cannot be sure Blender is in the same folder tree, I guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get it using `bpy.app.binary_path`

[Blender's API docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_72_release/bpy.app.html?highlight=binary_path#bpy.app.binary_path) say:

> `bpy.app.binary_path`:
>   The location of blenders executable, useful for utilities that spawn new instances`

Comment: ahhh, i tried googling exactly for that but didn't find it! thx!